# Visual Studio Installer won't open

Tags: visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-installer

I have Visual Studio 2022 and it works fine. But recently I tried to open Visual Studio Installer and it won't open. The message I get is Error, something went wrong.

Does someone know how to solve this? I have internet connection and I have tried to update Windows already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, if someone has the same problem: just delete Installer folder and install it again from Downloads.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/installation/troubleshoot-installation-issues

Close the Visual Studio Installer.
Delete the Visual Studio Installer folder. Typically, the folder path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer`.
Run the Visual Studio Installer bootstrapper. You might find the bootstrapper in your Downloads folder with a file name `VisualStudioSetup.exe` (Visual Studio 2022) or vs_*.exe (Visual Studio 2019 and previous versions). Or, you can download the bootstrapper from the download pages for Visual Studio 2022 or Visual Studio 2019 and previous versions. Then, run the executable to reset your installation metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to reinstall visual studio it happened to me once all you have to do is :

- Uninstall visual studio installer from the App & features in the settings for safety reasons
- Redownload visual studio installer from the official website : https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
- And you should be ready to go